# How do I associate a checkout_session with a payment using Firebase stripe extension?

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

As you might know, the Stripe payment extension for Firebase does the following:

1. Creates a `products` collection that gets filled with products managed in Stripe.
2. Creating a document under `customers/{id1}/checkout_sessions/{id2}` creates a payment in stripe. The document gets updated with the payment URL that the user can use to pay.
3. After paying, a document gets created by Stripe at `customers/{id1}/payments/{id3}`

How do you associate the payment that gets registered to the document in checkout_sessions?

The `checkout_session` document looks like

```
{
  cancel_url: (CancelUrl),
  client: "web",
  created: (Timestamp),
  mode: "payment",
  price: (The priceId associated to the product),
  sessionId: (The session id of the checkout_session),
  success_url: (SuccessUrl)
}
```

I create the `checkout_session` document myself, so I can add extra meta data in there but I'm not sure if Stripe can use it.

The `payment` document is significantly more complex. But the only id that I can associate to anything is the customer `stripeId` which appears as `customer` on the payment document.

Basically I'm trying to do the following.

1. A user creates a digital item with some custom properties (name, options, etc).
   This can happen during the creation of the `checkout_sessions` document.
2. They pay using the URL provided.
3. The `payments` document is created
4. This is where you help me figure out to validate that the payment they made is associated with the digital item created.

One idea that I have that will probably work is to do the following: Instead of allowing the creation of the digital item during the creation of the `checkout_sessions` document, I can create a "voucher" for that specific item. It won't have any personalization or options, but what I can do is create document onCreate cloud function on the payment document. If the payment is successful, allow the creation of the digital item. I can look up the 'template' based on the item purchased.

I dont like this option because there are at least 2 potential cold start delays that could make this a bad user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the `checkout_sessions` document, you can add a `metadata` object that can contain key:value pairs that will appear on the root of the document that is created in `payments` collection.

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to the `checkout.session.completed` event and retrieve the `line_items` of the checkout session object. From there you'll know what items are purchased successfully.

The details are explained in the integration [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#fulfill)

Comment: So firebase creates the `customers/{id1}/payments/{id3}` document after a payment is made. I can figure out what was purchased. I just would like to be able to associate the checkout_session with the purchase event itself.